# javascript radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am trying to make some project in which i want a text box to be displayed when I select expert button and no text box when i click on learner button....

I have written this code but not able to get the problem... Plz some help...

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript"> 

function toggleContent(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
    var text = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var ele = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
    var rad_val='';
    for (var i=0; i < document.text.role.length; i++)
    {
        if (document.text.role[i].checked)
        {
            rad_val = document.text.role[i].value;
        }
    }   

    if(rad_val=='learner'){
            ele.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr >
    <td  ><option value="1"> 1 </option>
    </td>
    <td> Role </td>
    <form id="form1">
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='learner' onClick="toggleContent('form1','div1')" >
        Learner </label>
      </td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='expert' onClick="toggleContent('form1','div1')" >
        Expert </label>
    </form>
<td ><div ID="div1" align=right style="display:none;">
        <label class="labell labelUser" >why?</label>
        <textarea name="description" align="right" id="description"  cols="40" rows="5" class="inputbox">Why?</textarea>
        <span id="descriptionError" class="notifyForUser" spanError></span> </div></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td  ><option value="2"> 2 </option>
    </td>
    <td> Role </td>
    <form id="form2">
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='learner' onClick=toggleContent('form2','div2') >
        Learner </label>
      </td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='expert' onClick=toggleContent('form2','div2') >
        Expert </label>
      </td>
    </form>
    <td ><div ID="div2" align=right style="display:none;">
        <label class="labell labelUser" >why?</label>
        <textarea name="description" align="right" id="description"  cols="40" rows="5" class="inputbox">Why?</textarea>
        <span id="descriptionError" class="notifyForUser" spanError></span> </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this problem is coming up because i have input tag inside td and label tags... but I don't know how can i solve this....

Comment: Remove document before every document.text. So document.text becomes text.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/PqgTK/

Comment: Your radios don't correctly grab the `<label>`. It should be `<input type="..." name="..." id="learner"> <label for="learner">Learner</label>`

Comment: Dude the solution is already posted down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. Thanks @dragon66 to solve my issue.

```
function toggleContent(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
    var text = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var ele = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
    var rad_val='';
    for (var i=0; i < text.role.length; i++)
    {
        if (text.role[i].checked)
        {
            rad_val = text.role[i].value;
        }
    }   

    if(rad_val=='learner'){
            ele.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr >
    <td  ><option value="1"> 1 </option>
    </td>
    <td> Role </td>
    <form id="form1">
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='learner' onClick="toggleContent('form1','div1')" >
        Learner </label>
      </td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='expert' onClick="toggleContent('form1','div1')" >
        Expert </label>
    </form>
<td ><div ID="div1" align=right style="display:none;">
        <label class="labell labelUser" >why?</label>
        <textarea name="description" align="right" id="description"  cols="40" rows="5" class="inputbox">Why?</textarea>
        <span id="descriptionError" class="notifyForUser" spanError></span> </div></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td  ><option value="2"> 2 </option>
    </td>
    <td> Role </td>
    <form id="form2">
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='learner' onClick=toggleContent('form2','div2') >
        Learner </label>
      </td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="role" value='expert' onClick=toggleContent('form2','div2') >
        Expert </label>
      </td>
    </form>
    <td ><div ID="div2" align=right style="display:none;">
        <label class="labell labelUser" >why?</label>
        <textarea name="description" align="right" id="description"  cols="40" rows="5" class="inputbox">Why?</textarea>
        <span id="descriptionError" class="notifyForUser" spanError></span> </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rad_val=='learner'){ 
        ele.style.display = "block"; 
} 
else { 
    ele.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

there is no value equals to learner, but learner1 or learner2

try this:

```
function toggleContent(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
    var text = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var ele = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
    var rad_val = '';
    var pattern = /\d+/g;
    var a=pattern.exec(showHideDiv);

    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[showHideDiv].role.length; i++) {
        if (document.forms[showHideDiv].role[i].checked) {
            rad_val = document.forms[showHideDiv].role[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (rad_val == 'learner' + a) {

        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {

        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggleContent(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
var text = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
var ele = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
var rad_val='';
var obj=text.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    if (obj[i].checked)
    {
        rad_val = obj[i].value;
    }
}  
if(rad_val.indexOf("learner")!=-1){
        ele.style.display = "block";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in the logic of your code and the way you retrieve the form elements.

Instead of fixing your code I would suggest revising the whole logic.

Better practice is binding the click event via code, not inline from within each input tag. Also, after clicking a radio button (also triggered from selecting with keyboard) you can assume for sure the selected value of the whole radio group is the value of the clicked button.

Here is the required code to achieve same effect:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("div2");
    var arrRoleButtons = document.getElementsByName("role");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrRoleButtons.length; i++) {
        var oCurrentRole = arrRoleButtons[i];
        oCurrentRole.onclick = function() {
            oDiv.style.display = (this.value === 'learner') ? "block" : "none"; 
        }
    }
};
```

Having this, you no longer need to call `onclick` from within the tags:

```
<input type="radio" name="role" value='learner' />
<input type="radio" name="role" value='expert' />
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/pnXF5/1/).

Comment: hey... I don't want to remove my td or label tag... I tried removing that but then I need it later for my project layout... I can't remove that... plz tell me what shall I do in the javascript to access it in the same way...

Comment: Don't remove anything in your HTML, just the inline `onclick` that's all. Instead of your current JavaScript code have only the code I posted and it should work fine.

Comment: I have two forms... and for both of them I want the same thing... in the above code it's actually getting confused which one to take....

Comment: Please upload your whole code to some free host like jsfiddle or jsbin and post link so I can see.